# How do I run some Scala code when the JVM starts?

Tags: scala, jvm

The problem I have is that I need to do some `System.properties` modifications and checks when the application starts AND when tests start running.

How do get code to run basically as soon as the JVM can start running code?  I tried a package object but I couldn't seem to get it to execute the code unless it was invoked.

Answer (score 3):

Just make all your test classes extend an abstract base class which calls the initialization code in the constructor.